# How can I use Plancherel theorem here?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, gaussian-integral

I am given the function $f(x)=e^{-x^4}$

I am asked if it is true that $\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{\infty}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{-\infty}}  |\hat f(w)|^2\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}\class{main-var-unused-warning}{w}}=1$

Well I am not sure how and if I should use Plancherel theorem here, I understand that $f$ is a kind of gaussian and if I understood correctly, fourier transform of gaussian is another gaussian, which seems logic for me that this is true, but how I can actually prove it or deny it by using theorems and avoiding complicated calculations?

Comment: Doesn't the plancherel theorem state $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2 dx = C \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(\omega)|^2 d\omega$, where $C$ is a constant that depends on how you define $\hat{f}$? The thing to do then would be to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2 dx$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I dont think so, we got it in a test with no calculator or formulas

Comment: Maybe not then. The integral is nothing simple (you can check wolframalpha). Perhaps you want to make some argument that shows $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx > 1$. Using a lower Riemann sum might work.

Comment: The function $f(x) = e^{x^{-4}}$ has a very strong (non-integrable) singularity at the origin, so I'm not even sure how the Fourier transform would be defined here. Or is the function supposed to be $e^{-x^4}$? That would be closer in form to a Gaussian.

Comment: @Jason ohh I did mean to $e^{-x^4}$ now I understand why no one answered me thank you for this note